# F# Reactive wait for Observable to complete

Tags: f#, system.reactive, xunit

I found a variety of SO questions on this but couldn't figure out an F# solution. I need to block wait for an event to fire at me to check the data it returns. I am using Rx to receive event 3 times:

```
let disposable =
    Observable.take 3 ackNack
    |> Observable.subscribe (
        fun (sender, data) ->
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", data.AckNack)
            Assert.True(data.TotalAckCount > 0u)
    )
```

I would like to either turn results into a list, so they can be checked later on by the test framework (xUnit), or wait for all 3 events to complete and pass the `Assert.True`.

How would I wait for 3 events to fire before continuing? I can see there's an `Observable.wait` other sources suggest `Async.RunSynchronously`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the easiest option is to use `Async.AwaitObservable` function - sadly, this is not yet available in the F# core library, but you can get it from the FSharpx.Async package, or just copy the [function soruce from GitHub](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Async/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Async/Observable.fs#L290).

Using the function, you should be able to write something like:

```
let _, data = 
  Observable.take 3 ackNack
  |> Async.AwaitObservable
  |> Async.RunSynchronously

Console.WriteLine("{0}", data.AckNack)
Assert.True(data.TotalAckCount > 0u)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer again Tomas! :) I will try the Async package.

Comment: Does exactly what I was trying to achieve. I appreciate your help Tomas, on both my questions :)

Comment: I just cannot get `Async.AwaitObservable` to work .
I have installed every nuget I can find that seems to reference it, but I cannot find that function.

Comment: I'm not sure where this lives nowadays, but you should be able to get it just by copying the source code from GitHub...